# Arithmetic derivatives and non-commutative generalizations

Tags: nt.number-theory, noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-geometry

In the theory of arithmetic derivatives, in the simplest case an arithmetic derivative on $\mathbb{N}$ is defined via the rule $(a \times b)'= a \times b' + a' \times b$, mirroring the product rule from standard calculus. We need to define values on primes, 0 and 1 are determined by this rule to be 0, the standard choice on primes is 1, but the assignment at primes can possibly vary. There are generalizations to unique factorization domains (How to differentiate a number, Ufnarovski & Åhlander) and rings modulo n (How to differentiate an integer modulo n by Emmons, Krebs & Shaheen). Now I am wondering what would happen if we weaken the commutativity of both $+$ and $\times$.

Are there definitions of derivatives be it from function calculus, already existing arithmetic analogues or otherwise, that could inspire a form of non-commutative product rule for non-commutative UFDs/near-rings, the way standard commutative product rule inspires the definition for UFDs/rings? Is there some sort of a uniform product rule in the case of differentiation of functions on non-commutative structures?

Edit 1st november 2023: I found the paper EXISTENCE OF DERIVATIONS ON NEAR-RINGS,and similarly left and right derivations seems to be the correct keywords, for 2 cases which coincide in case of commutativity of multiplication. But I still need to read more of the references before being able to answer my own question

Edit 2nd november 2023: that paper requires the derivations to be additive mappings which excludes the arithmetic derivatives at $\mathbb{N}$